# Better way to react to HTML window close event

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight-5.0

My Silverlight, at one point, needs to open a new browser window. This isn't an issue.

But I'm having problems reacting to the opened window being closed (I need to refresh data). Now, this wouldn't have been a problem if not for the fact that the new page I open can (and does) perform callbacks. As such, `onbeforeunload` event isn't as useful, because it'll be fired not only when the window is closed, but also when the page performs a callback.

Here's the code I've currently got.

```
    private void OpenAnnotation()
    {
        var window = HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(/*url goes here*/)),
            "_newWindow", "toolbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1");
        SetWindowCallback(window, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)); //Delay needed, the OS needs at least some time to display the new window.
    }

    private void SetWindowCallback(HtmlWindow window, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
            UIDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (window != null && Helpers.HtmlWindow.WindowExists(window)) //WindowExists attemts to do Invoke("this") on the HtmlWindow; if it fails, it's likely the window doesn't exist
                {
                    window.Eval(@"this.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', 
function(){
    var slObject = window.opener.document.getElementById('SL');
    if (slObject != null)
        slObject.Content.AnnotationControl.UpdateAttachmentInfo(this);
});");
                }
            });
        });
    }


    [ScriptableMember]
    public void UpdateAttachmentInfo(HtmlWindow window)
    {
        SetBusyIndicator(true);
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            LoadAnnotation();
            SetWindowCallback(window, TimeSpan.Zero);
        });
    }
```

I really "just" want to refresh my data when the window is closed, but it seems I'm limited to JS, and that, in turn, reacts to mentioned callbacks.

Is there any better way of doing this?

PS. I cannot chance the code of the page I'm opening! I can only work with my SL application.

Comment: i am having same problem, but I am OK to do with JS, but when I am attaching a onbeforeunload event with window.Eval I am getting Eval failed error. Any idea?

Comment: If you've tried the code I wrote and you're getting an error, it might be due to a different page layout. For example, in my case, the Silverlight object has been given an ID "SL" (the pages generated by VS do not assign any ID to the Silverlight object). If not that, then I can only suggest you start a JS debugger (F12 in Internet Explorer) and try to manually check your `Eval` code. Or, just to be on the safe side, try to `Eval` something like `alert('It's OK')`.

Comment: I have exactly tried the same like simple alert('test') in Eval but same error "Eval Failed", can you please tell me where I can define the id SL

Comment: If you're getting "Eval Failed" errors even when trying to run a simple `alert('something');` code, then you have bigger problems than the ID. :P But if you insist, just add `ID="SL"` to the Silverlight `<object>` tag on the HTML page hosting said Silverlight.

Comment: Yes, i have given the id"SL" to <object> still Eval failed....seems i have a very big problem here......

Comment: Like I wrote, try to `Eval` something simple at first.

Comment: I have tried `Eval("alert('Rohit')")`  but no luck :-(

Comment: I don't suppose the exception you're getting has any useful information inside? What browser are you using? Is it running in protected mode?

Comment: I am using IE 7 , and i dont have any idea about protected mode of browser.

Comment: Uhm... perhaps there's your problem then? Did you try updating IE?